# Airflow - prevent DAG from running immediately during import

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I have a DAG that has below Steps :-

1. Retrieve a list of items from an API call
2. For each item in the list, spin up another task that prints the value.

Basically, step 2 is indeterministic until the API call is made. I want the API call to be made only after I trigger a DAG run.

However, the Step1 of the DAG is being executed while importing the DAG itself, and if the API call is not working, then it reports DAG as broken. The entire thing is supposed to be dynamic.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import requests

# Default args for the DAG
default_args = {
    'owner': 'me',
    'start_date': datetime(2025, 1, 1),
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

# Create a DAG instance
dag = DAG(
    'my_dag_id',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule=None,
)

def get_items():
    """
    Makes a HTTP request to an API,
    retrieves a list of items from the response,
    and returns the list
    """
    response = requests.get('https://api.example.com/items')
    items = response.json()['items']
    return items

def process_item(item):
    """
    Processes a single item
    """
    print(f'Processing item {item}')

# Create a PythonOperator to get the items
get_items_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='get_items',
    python_callable=get_items,
    dag=dag,
)

# Create a PythonOperator to process each item
for item in get_items():
    task = PythonOperator(
        task_id=f'process_item_{item}',
        python_callable=process_item,
        op_args=[item],
        dag=dag,
    )
    task.set_upstream(get_items_task)
```

Notice that I have set **start date to future** and **schedule=None**.
As soon as I save this `py` file in the /dags folder, it immediately executes the **get_items_task** and reports that DAG is broken because the **get_items** api call returned error.

How can I stop the task from getting executed while importing DAG?
I want it to be dynamic i.e., fetch list of items only once the DAG is triggered, and then only create tasks for each of those items dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `get_items()` in the global scope of the DAG file (statement `for item in get_items():`). This gets evaluated every time Airflow parses the DAG file.

To avoid `get_items()` getting executed in the global scope, you can place this functionality in a function, to only generate tasks at runtime. For this use case, [dynamic task mapping](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/dynamic-task-mapping.html) was introduced in Airflow. This allows you to generate a varying number of tasks given a collection of items.

I've refactored your DAG to generate tasks in the `process_item` task given the output of `get_items`:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import requests
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task

# Default args for the DAG
default_args = {
    "owner": "me",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "retries": 1,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
}

# Create a DAG instance
with DAG(
    "my_dag_id",
    default_args=default_args,
    start_date=datetime(2025, 1, 1),
    schedule=None,
):

    @task
    def get_items():
        """
        Makes a HTTP request to an API,
        retrieves a list of items from the response,
        and returns the list
        """
        response = requests.get("https://api.example.com/items")
        items = response.json()["items"]
        return items

    @task
    def process_item(item):
        """
        Processes a single item
        """
        print(f"Processing item {item}")

    process_item.expand(item=get_items())
```

`expand()` generates a task for each element in the output of `get_items()`. The TaskFlow API (`@task` decorator) is convenient when dealing with dynamically generated tasks, read more about it in the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/taskflow.html).

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and there is no import error. However, even after I manually trigger the DAG, the DAG run is success, but the tasks are not executed as per the graph page. Is there something missing ?

Comment: That's because your `start_date` is in the future. With default settings, that won't run tasks. You can configure `AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__ALLOW_TRIGGER_IN_FUTURE=True` + trigger with a logical date after 01-01-2025 to execute DAG runs for future dates. Easier would be to change your start date to a date in the past, e.g. `start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1)`.